# php cURL. preg_match , extract text from xhtml

Tags: php, curl, preg-match

I'm trying to extract the price from the bellow html page/link using php cURL and preg_match . Basically I'm expecting for this code to output 4,550 but for some reasons I get

```
 Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\test.php on line 22
```

I think that the pattern is correct because if I put the html itself in a variable and escape the "" it works ! .
  Also if I output (echo $result;) it displays the html properly grabbed from foxtons website so I just can't figure it out why the whole thing doesn't work . I need to make this work and also I would appreciate if you would tell me why is that notice generated and why my current script  doesn't work.

```
$url = "http://www.foxtons.co.uk/search?bedrooms_from=0&property_id=727717";
$ch = curl_init($url);
```

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$result2 = str_replace('"', '\"', $result);

$tagname1= ");</script>
    ";
 $tagname2= "</noscript> 
    per month</a>";

`$pattern = "/$tagname1(.*?)$tagname2/";
preg_match($pattern, $result, $matches);
$prices = $matches[1];

print_r($prices);

?>`

Comment: Why are you defining $result2 if you don't use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote the script a bit to account for more than 1 <noscript> on the page. You needed to use preg_match_all which will look for all the matches not just stop at the first one.

```
$url = "http://www.foxtons.co.uk/search?bedrooms_from=0&property_id=727717";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

preg_match_all("/<noscript>(.*)<\/noscript>/", $result, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Outputs

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => £1,050
            [1] => 4,550
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => £1,050
            [1] => 4,550
        )

)
```

I tried this on my box and it worked - let me know if it worked for you

Comment: yes it works on mine too. I will set your answer as accepted but I would appreciate if you would explain me why my script doesn't work so I can understand what's wrong with it .
regards,
Michael !

Comment: a few things I see - 1) you shouldn't need to escape the quotes

2) Use preg_match_all vs preg_match, preg_match_all finds all the matches vs the first match (which in this case is not the result you were looking for)

3) you used * and ? in the pattern string, ? matches zero or one time, * matches zero or more times

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use REGEX to parse html**, use an html dom parser instead, like [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

```
include("simple_html_dom.php") ;

$html = file_get_html("http://www.foxtons.co.uk/search?bedrooms_from=0&property_id=727717");

foreach($html->find('noscript') as $noscript)
{

    echo $noscript->innertext."<br>";
}
```

echo's:

```
£1,600
6,934
£1,500
6,500
£1,350
5,850
£950
4,117
£925
4,009
£850
3,684
£795
3,445
£795
3,445
£775
3,359
£750
3,250
```