# How to get data from url link to our website

Tags: php, schedule

I have a problem with my website. I want to get all the schedule flight data from another website. I see its source code and get the url link for processing data. Can somebody tell me how to get the data from the current url link, then display it to our website with PHP?

Comment: Sounds like scraping. What's the link, and is there an API that you could be using?

Comment: it is scraping. you want [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php‎) and [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php). Hopefully you have asked permission of the other website

Answer (score 6):

You can do it using `file_get_contents()` function. this function return html of provided url. then use HTML Parser to get required data.

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://website.com");

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('h3');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue."<br>"; // return <h3> tag data
}
```

Another way to extract data using `preg_match_all()`

```
$html = file_get_contents($_REQUEST['url']);

preg_match_all('/<div class="swrapper">(.*?)<\/div>/s', $html, $matches);
   // specify the class to get the data of that class
foreach ($matches[1] as $node) {
    echo $node."<br><br><br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Sample code

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes Sure ... Use  `file_get_contents('$URl')` function to get the source code of the target page or use curl if you prefer using  curl .. and scrap all data you need with `preg_match_all()` function

Note : If the target url has https:// then you should use  curl to get the source code

Example

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838253/php-curl-preg-match-extract-text-from-xhtml`